# Directly connecting MIPI Camera and Display

Tags: circuit-design, display, imageprocessing, image-sensor

I have a little bit of a hard time wrapping my mind around MIPI.

**My mission:**
I want to connect a MIPI camera directly to a MIPI display.

Camera pin-layout:

[image]

Display pin-layout:

[image]

The Interface of the display is defined by the retailer as DSI.

**My Problem:**
I would like to know if a direct connection is possible. If not, what's the problem and how can I solve it? If possible, I would like to do it without any signal processing.

I'm thankful for all resources and help!

Comment: The screen uses MIPI DSI, the camera uses MIPI CSI. Even though both standards are published by the same organisation, they are not meant to be compatible. There are a few common things, but there are probably more differences than commonality, in general, and in this specific instance (like the display using a 2 channel 4 lane interface while the camera uses a single channel). The resolution of the two devices is also probably quite different, isn’t it?

Comment: This doesn't come as a surprise. You are right, the camera outputs a 720p image while the display has a 1600x1600 pxl resolution. I was hoping to find a way to make this work. They word here is latency. We cannot afford having a huge delay from sensor to display.

Comment: please quantify `huge delay` ... add to your post, not here in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I'm going with will be CSI -> HDMI -> DSI.
I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it'll spare me a lot of time working on software, since this is a project that's supposed to be recreated and used by inexperienced users easily.
I'm now working on hardware design based on open-source systems.

This is part of the BPNVG/DBNVG development.

Answer (score 0):

While your camera module and display might share the same electrical interface, I doubt that the data formatting of the MIPI stream that the sensor generates is anything that a display can work with. I've never seen the two linked together directly like that. How do you plan on getting the image size of the sensor adjusted to that of the panel?
You really need some kind of kind of processor to handle both devices. I think the Rpi is able to handle MIPI. Beefy microcontrollers with media engines like STM32F7 might work as well.
If you have parts numbers for both that might be helfull...

Comment: The image size is something I worry about another time. I was hoping that I can do a minimalist work around the MCU so I can keep latency down.

Comment: Any decent processor would be able to have 'low latency', which is subjective (actual figure?). I really fear that directly hooking a panel and camera sensor together is not feasible. It's not about you not worrying about image size and data formatting, but its about whether the panel can work with the signal you are going to provide to it.
There are lot of small low-cost system-on-modules that can do what you want. If you make a careful selection of the module and supporting software, then a lot of work should already be done for you in terms of interfacing with MIPI devices.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention. We defined low-latency to about 20 ms from sensor to screen.
In any case, this is what I'm pursuing right now. I will now look for a simple interface solution.
Can you point me in any direction? My experience in this area is very limited.

Comment: 20ms sounds doable really. In terms of processing, you want something with lots of support so you dont waste your own time on getting OS and libraries up and running. This module: https://www.variscite.com/product/system-on-module-som/cortex-a53-krait/dart-mx8m-plus-nxp-i-mx-8m-plus/ can run some kind of linux and has MIPI input for camera (p. 51 datasheet) and MIPI output for display (p. 49 datasheet). Im no embedded software designer so I cant say anything about the firmware. The engineer I worked with back then said something about 'enabling interfaces in the device tree'. No idea;)

Comment: Other SoM's you can look into are the Raspberry Pi, and modules from Toradex. There exist others but i have no experience with them. If you feel uncomfortable making a carrier board for these modules, the manufacturers usually sell development kits that break out all the interfaces of the SoM for you to use. But hooking up such a high-speed sensor and display is going to more then some jumpers. Be sure to check with your sensor/panel manufacturer if they make adapters to the connector your development board is offering

Comment: I bumped into the 96 Boards DragonBoard 410c that natively supports MIPI CSI and DSI. They all seem to have a lot of processing power and the development boards are big. I will have to find a good way for prototyping and later integration.
Thank you!

Comment: 20 ms is basically one frame. As long as you can process framed in real time it should do. Probably easier with a processor which integrated a VPU (more likely things based on ARM A-series than M-series, but there are probably exceptions).